# filter rows based on a series of columns

Tags: python, filter

i have a dataframe with 50 columns and 7777 rows. the first 4 columns are object type and all the remaining are int type. i would to like to filter the dataframe if all the columns from column 3 to column 50 are zero. kindly help me filter using python

tried :

```py
df.apply(lambda row: row[df.iloc[:,3:].isin(['0'])])
```

error:

```
TypeError: Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column
```

Comment: Something like - `df.loc[(df.iloc[:,3:]=='0').all(axis=1)]`.  I think axis=1 is correct.

Comment: awesome !! works perfect. what does ".all" stands for and does it have other alterations

Answer (score 0):

Your filter condition is - rows where [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) of the values for columns 3+ equal 0. Use [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with the boolean result.

```
df.loc[(df.iloc[:,3:]=='0').all(axis=1)]
```

---

[Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data)